# How to run PCA on existing correlation matrix, then run regression?

Tags: r, machine-learning, nlp, pca

I currently have calculated pairwise correlation between survey respondents, and stored it in a dataframe. It looks like this:

```
          person_1 person_2 person_3
 person_1.  0        1.5     1.8
 person_2.  1.5       0      2.2
 person_3.  1.8      2.2.      0
```

Now I'd like to run PCA analysis to find loadings for each response. I have 2 questions:

1. Which function should I use to calculate PC using the correlation matrix directly?
2. On a related note. I'd like to then regress each respondent's loading on the person's survey rating score in the original dataframe. Is there a way for me to merge the "score" column back into the function to run regression? Or is there another way to do the regression/prediction?

The original dataframe is a text dataframe and looks like this. I then run word mover distance between sentences to derive the correlation matrix.

```
          text.                      score
person_1. I like working at Apple       2
person_2  the culture is great          -2
person_3. pandemic hits                 5
```

Thanks!

Comment: You do not have a correlation matrix. The correlation with a variable and itself is always 1 not 0. You have some kind of a distance matrix so this data may not be applicable to PCA unless you have the raw data that produced the distance matrix. With a distance matrix you could cluster people and look at how the clusters match up with your survey ratings.

Comment: I see. You are right. The original dataframe is text data. Which clustering method would you propose? I was thinking of K-means, but not sure if it can be used to run a regression analysis with the quant variable I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have a matrix, sometimes most of known algorithms for PCA in `R` use to have issues with tolerance so they return error. I would suggest next approach using `eigen()` function which replicates the essence of PCA. Next the code:

```
#Data
#Matrix
mm <- structure(c(0, 1.5, 1.8, 1.5, 0, 2.2, 1.8, 2.2, 0), .Dim = c(3L, 
3L), .Dimnames = list(c("person_1", "person_2", "person_3"), 
    c("person_1", "person_2", "person_3")))
#Scores
df1 <- structure(list(text. = c("I like working at Apple", "the culture is great", 
"pandemic hits"), score = c(2L, -2L, 5L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")
```

The code for PCA would be next:

```
#PCA
myPCA <- eigen(mm)
#Squares of sd computed by princomp
myPCA$values
```

Output:

```
[1]  3.681925 -1.437762 -2.244163
```

In order to get loadings, we use this:

```
#Loadings
myPCA$vectors
```

Output:

```
          [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.5360029  0.8195308 -0.2026578
[2,] -0.5831254 -0.5329938 -0.6130925
[3,] -0.6104635 -0.2104444  0.7635754
```

With previous outputs we create a dataframe for regression:

```
#Format loadings 
Vectors <- data.frame(myPCA$vectors)
names(Vectors) <- colnames(mm)
#Prepare to regression
#Create data
mydf <- cbind(df1[,c('score'),drop=F],Vectors)
```

Output:

```
  score   person_1   person_2   person_3
1     2 -0.5360029  0.8195308 -0.2026578
2    -2 -0.5831254 -0.5329938 -0.6130925
3     5 -0.6104635 -0.2104444  0.7635754
```

Finally the code for regressions would be this:

```
#Build models
lm(score~person_1,data=mydf)
lm(score~person_2,data=mydf)
lm(score~person_3,data=mydf)
```

Last models can be saved in new objects if you want. An example would be:

```
m1 <- lm(score~person_1,data=mydf)
summary(m1)
```

Output:

```
Call:
lm(formula = score ~ person_1, data = mydf)

Residuals:
     1      2      3 
 1.411 -3.842  2.431 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   -13.66      51.60  -0.265    0.835
person_1      -26.58      89.37  -0.297    0.816

Residual standard error: 4.76 on 1 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.08127,   Adjusted R-squared:  -0.8375 
F-statistic: 0.08846 on 1 and 1 DF,  p-value: 0.816
```

Comment: Thanks! how to interpret that the loadings between 1 & 2 and 2& 1 are different?

Comment: In my experience using PCA I would suggest two approaches. First, you can take each vector of loading and plot it into one dimension then compare all one dim plots and extract insights. Second, compute the correlation between score variable and loadings and see relationships `cor(mydf)` could help.